# Присвоить фразе теги и сравнить их с базой вариаций тегов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Присвоить фразе теги и сравнить их с базой тегов. При совпадении вывести сообщение true.

Фраза: *"Как у тебя дела"*

```
//теги
  const имя = /зовут|звать|имя|прозвище|кличка|называют/giu;
  const бот = /ты|тебя|тво(е|ё|й|я)|ва(с|ш)|свое/giu;
  const допрос = /что|где|чем|как|скажи|назови|поведай|ответь/giu;
  const приветствие = /привет|здаров|здрав|х(а|э)й/giu;
  const приветствие2 = (/добр(ый|ое|ой) (день|утро|вечер|ночи)/giu);
  const настроение = /настроение|жизн(ь|и)|поживае(шь|те)|оно|сам|дела|делишки/giu
  const просьба = /есть|будет|да(й|шь|те)/giu
  const действие = /делаешь|маешься|занят|происходит|случилось|творишь|нов(еньк)?ого/giu
```

База вариантов тегов

```
1 = имя
2 = имя, бот
3 = имя, бот, допрос
4 = приветствие || приветствие 2
5 = настроение, бот, допрос
6 = допрос, действие
7 ...
```

Я попытался реализовать это через цикл

Создал массив всех массивов:

```
let tags = [имя, бот, допрос, приветствие, приветствие2, настроение, просьба, действие]
```

И прописал цикл:

```
for (let index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
     const element = tags[index];
     console.log("как у тебя дела".match(element)) 
}
```

В итоге я получил соответствия из каждого элемента массива, но как присвоить значения определенным переменным (тегам) - незнаю.

[image: консоль]

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете объявить словарь с названиями "тегов" в качестве ключей и соответствующие регурярные выражения в качестве значений. При нахождении совпадения присваивайте фразе найденный тег.

См. пример кода:

```js
const slovar = {
  "имя": /зовут|звать|имя|прозвище|кличка|называют/gi,
  "бот": /ты|тебя|тво(е|ё|й|я)|ва(с|ш)|свое/gi,
  "допрос": /что|где|чем|как|скажи|назови|поведай|ответь/gi,
  "приветствие": /привет|здаров|здрав|х(а|э)й/gi,
  "приветствие2": /добр(ый|ое|ой) (день|утро|вечер|ночи)/gi,
  "настроение": /настроение|жизн(ь|и)|поживае(шь|те)|оно|сам|дела|делишки/gi,
  "просьба": /есть|будет|да(й|шь|те)/gi,
  "действие": /делаешь|маешься|занят|происходит|случилось|творишь|нов(еньк)?ого/gi 
}

const text = "как у тебя дела";
for (const kluch in slovar) {
    if (slovar[kluch].test(text)) {
        console.log(kluch);
    }
}
```

Тут фразе "как у тебя дела" присваиваются три тега: "бот", "допрос" и "настроение".

Comment: А как сравнить с базой вариантов тегов?